# How can I save a dictionary to SwiftData?

Tags: swift, swift-data

In my app I have a property of my object which is a Dictionary  [String: NSAttributedString] which I would like to save to SwiftData.

I cannot create a struct for this property because it will be dynamic and the user can dynamically add key/value pairs to the dictionary.

What would be the best way to save this to SwiftData?  I'm thinking I have to serialize it to a Data type and save it like that but wondering if there was any other way?

Another approach I tried is the following but I don't know how to decode it back?

```
// Encode
let dictionary: [String: NSAttributedString] = ["First Key" : NSAttributedString(string: "First Value")]
do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary)
    // save it to SwiftData
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// Decode
let dictionary: [String: NSAttributedString] = JSONDecoder().decode([String: NSAttributedString].self, from: data)
```

But here I get the error:

```
Class 'JSONDecoder' requires that 'NSAttributedString' conform to 'Decodable'
```

Not sure how to overcome this.

Comment: Dictionary is not a problem. It's the attributed string that is a problem. Don't save complex data like `NSAttributedString` to storage. How do you think fonts would be stored?

Comment: Two options: 1) Use native `AttributedString` which conforms to `Codable`. 2) `NSAttributedString` conforms to `NSSecureCoding`, it can be serialized as a transformable attribute

Comment: @vadian when I convert my NSAttributedString to an AttributedString I lose some of the characteristics like the NSParagraphStyle for markers.  So I really need to store as an NSAttributedString

Answer (score 0):

> Class 'JSONDecoder' requires that 'NSAttributedString' conform to 'Decodable'

The error you provided indicates that the problem is with `NSAttributedString`, not with the dictionary.

So to fix this, you need to use an instance that conforms to `Codable`. You either have to choose another type, or convert `NSAttributedString` into `Data`.

You can do this as the following:

**Create an `extension` that handles converting from and to `Data`**:

```swift
extension NSAttributedString {
    static func get(from data: Data?) -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data else { return nil }
        var attributedString: NSAttributedString?
        do {
            attributedString = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSAttributedString.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("Error converting Data to NSAttributedString: \(error)")
        }
        return attributedString
    }
    
    var data: Data? {
        var data: Data?
        do {
            data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self,
                                                    requiringSecureCoding: false)
        } catch {
            print("Error converting NSAttributedString to Data: \(error)")
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

**Use it**:

```swift
let dictionaryWithData: [String: Data] =
  ["First Key" :
    NSAttributedString(string: "First Value").data]

var dict: [String: NSAttributedString?] {
  dictionaryWithData.mapValues { data in
    NSAttributedString.get(from: data)
  }
}
```